# Input array has random 0s at random positions: Java (mergeSort)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, mergesort

My input array for my merge sort algorithm has random 0s at random positions:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class MRS

{
public static int [] A = new int [8];
public static int [] workArray = new int [8];

public static void mergeSort(int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int middle = (left + right) / 2;
        mergeSort(left, middle);
        mergeSort(middle+1, right);
        Merge(left, middle, right);
    }
}


public static void Merge(int left, int mid, int right)
{
    int leftIterator = left;
    int rightIterator = mid+1;


    int workArrayIterator = left;
    //for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) System.out.print(A[j] + " ");

    while (leftIterator <= mid && rightIterator < right)
    {
        if (A[leftIterator] <= A[rightIterator])
        {
            workArray[workArrayIterator] = A[leftIterator];
            leftIterator++;

        }
        else
        {
            workArray[workArrayIterator] = A[rightIterator];
            rightIterator++;

        }

        workArrayIterator++;
    }

    while (leftIterator <= mid)
    {
        workArray[workArrayIterator] = A[leftIterator];
        leftIterator++;
        workArrayIterator++;
    }

    /*while (rightIterator < right)
    {
        workArray[workArrayIterator] = A[rightIterator];
            rightIterator++;
            workArrayIterator++;
    }*/

    for (int i = left; i < right; i++) A[i] = workArray[i];

}

public static void main (String[] a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) A[i] = (int)(Math.random()*50);

    //for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) System.out.print(A[j] + " ");

    mergeSort(0, 8);

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) System.out.print(A[j] + " ");
}

}
```

The last line above outputs the correct numbers at first, but iteration after iteration, the array gets filled with 0s up to the point when it is 75% 0s. Just a clarification, that line is for debug purposes only as I kept getting all 0s as the output of this algorithm.

I tried passing a local array in main() as argument to mergeSort and Merge --> all 0s

I tried having global class arrays --> all 0s or random 0s

If you'd like me to post the rest of the code (about 25 lines), do let me know.

Thank you for all your suggestions.

**EDIT**:After examining my iterators, I noticed a problem and fixed it, so I don't get all 0s anymore. However, I do not get a fully sorted array. Some integers are still out of place.

Comment: Well, it would definitely be helpful to see the rest of the `Merge` method, because this apparently is the place were something goes wrong.

Comment: "If you'd like me to post the rest of the code (about 25 lines), do let me know." You should do it without anyone's asking: these 25 lines make your program complete. After all, you've already posted 25 lines; doubling that wouldn't hurt ;-)

Comment: I just know how you guys hate reading long poorly written programs :)

Comment: maybe try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @arunmoezhi: Code Review is only for _working_ code.  This question would be off-topic there.

Comment: @Aroll605 Sure, but poorly written *incomplete* programs are even worse. If you're removing parts of the program, make sure that what's left still exhibits the problem. Otherwise, it becomes difficult to help (we're terrible guessers)

Comment: @Aroll605 we've seen code that's much worse than this.

Comment: :)) Thank you for your support! So far, I have fixed the all 0s problem -- it was an iterator issue. I have one last problem however: one digit in an 8 member array is out of place after the sort. My guess would be that it's an iterator issue as well but I can't find it. The code above is the latest code I have: it only has one bug.